# Do I need a transit visa for my Bangkok layover?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, bangkok, dmk

I am an Indian passport holder traveling   from  Cambodia to Taiwan (Taipei)  via Thailand (Don Mueang airport Bangkok). On the way there, the layover is 2 hours. Do I need a transit visa for Thailand?

Cambodia to Thailand (REP to MDK Airport) on Air Asia.
Thailand to Taiwan (MDK to TPE Airport) on Nokscoot airline.

Comment: If you have checked luggage, then *definitely* yes, because neither AirAsia nor NokScoot allow interlining. If you don't, then *most probably* yes, because AFAIK NokScoot only allows check-in at landside counters in DMK.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> If you have checked luggage, then definitely yes, because neither AirAsia nor NokScoot allow interlining. If you don't, then most probably yes, because AFAIK NokScoot only allows check-in at landside counters in DMK.